# Reproducibility issue between GPU graphic cards for DNN Tensorflow models

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, gpu, reproducibility

I am facing reproducibility issues on my DNN (Tensorflow, Keras) models when using different GPU cards. For example, when I use two a100 cards, I would be able to reproduce my results. If I use one a100 and one v100, the results will be different and not reproduce. I want to ask, is this to be expected, or can I control this? I wasn't sure if there was a bug in my code, but it seems like the benchmark difference is stochastic. I want to be able to reproduce for the purpose of biomedical research.

At the beginning of my DNN model class, I call this function:

```
def set_tf_seed(n):
    """
    Sets all necessary random seeds with a randomly generated number n
    :param n: int, random number generated from a random number generator
    :return:
    """
    os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(n)
    random.seed(n)
    np.random.seed(n)
    tf.random.set_seed(n)
```

I also wanted to test whether the reproduction was an issue in the buildmodel or prediction stage. After some testing, it is able to predict with reproducibility, regardless of which card it is on when doing the prediction. The buildmodel, however, is not able to.

I also wondered whether there was precision differences between the two cards in the beginning. I have the following line at the beginning of the py file and it prints out "precision float32". I'm not sure if this is the correct code but here it is:

```
print('precision', tf.keras.backend.floatx())
```

I also have some environmental variables that I control at the top level, along with optimizing the GPU usage/memory allocation. I wanted to include this as additional information.

```
# Optimizes GPU usage and allocates memory accordingly
import tensorflow as tf
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)
gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
    try:
        # Currently, memory growth needs to be the same across GPUs
        for gpu in gpus:
            tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
        logical_gpus = tf.config.list_logical_devices('GPU')
        print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
    except RuntimeError as e:
        # Memory growth must be set before GPUs have been initialized
        print(e)

# turn off system warnings
import logging
logging.getLogger("tensorflow").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
# keeping environment variable fixed to prevent unwanted randomness
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
tf.autograph.set_verbosity(0)
os.environ['TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS'] = '1'
```